# Format a decimal without comma

Tags: c#, .net, decimal

i try to format a decimal as 0:0.0 in c# 
tried this code

```
string nv = textBox7.Text.Trim().Replace(',', '.');

res =  Convert.ToDecimal(nv, new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
```

but res always show a result with a comma, tried also with

```
new CultureInfo("en-GB")
```

but the problem persist 
And thank you in advance.

Comment: `res` is a `decimal`, not a string. So it can't have a format.

Comment: What does `0:0.0` even mean for a `decimal`? What is the meaning of the `:`?

Comment: @Oded I guess it stands for `0`th parameter in `string.Format`.

Comment: @CodeInChaos - It's a good guess and what I also assume, but would like the OP to explain, since it is not entirely clear.

Comment: What the debugger shows for the value for *res* has nothing to do with the way it will be stored in the dbase.  Make sure your dbase column is numeric and not text.

Answer (score 20):

As other comments and answers suggest, you have some basics to understand first. I may be saying some things you already know, but bear with me:

1. Your `textBox7.Text` contains a `string`, not a `decimal`.
2. If you want a `decimal` for calculations, you have to convert it (I think you already got this far)
3. Since `res` is a decimal, whenever you want to look at its value SOMETHING will convert it to a `string`. Whether that's you writing it to the `Console` or your debugger when you mouse over it. That conversion will use your current Regional Settings. **This** is why you always see a comma.
4. To show it to somebody else or write it somewhere with the format YOU want, you'll have to specify a format or a CultureInfo.

a) [Standard Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Example:
`Console.WriteLine(res.toString("F2"));`
This will format 123456 with 2 numbers after the decimal point: 123456.00

b) [Custom Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Example:
`Console.WriteLine(res.toString("[##-##-##]"));`
This will output 123456 to something like [12-34-56]

c) [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ebe5aks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Example:
`Console.WriteLine(res.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nl-BE")));`
This will output 1234.56 like in Belgium: with a comma 1234,56
Incidentally, I think en-GB also outputs to a comma :-)

d) [Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18sthszb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Go nuts! Do both ! Example:
`Console.WriteLine(res.ToString("F2", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nl-BE")));`
formats 123456 to 123456,00 !

Based on that I'd suggest the following:

```
decimal res = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox7.Text, new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
```

This assumes your users enter the number using a comma (since the en-GB decimal separator is a comma). If not, use the correct CultureInfo like Invariant of en-US.

Answer (score 3):

`res` is a `decimal`, not a string. So it can't have a format. Decimals are pure mathematical numbers without an associated format. The format only comes into existence when you convert a `decimal` to a `string`.

You can use `res.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` to produce a string that uses `.` as decimal separator.

Comment: i would like to have a decimal to insert it in my database,

Comment: @user And where is your problem?

Comment: the problem is solved, i thought that i should use a decimal variable to use it an sqlCommand instruction, but also a string can make the same think, i used string nv = textBox7.Text.Trim().Replace(',', '.');

Comment: @user1348165 I don't understand you, but `Replace(',', '.')` is certainly not the right answer.

Comment: possible you want `decimal.ToString(decimal.Parse(input,someCulture), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`, but you're so vague that I don't understand your actual problem.

Comment: @tarek This is of course very late, but if you want to use something the user types in in an SqlCommand you should NEVER directly insert it (your replace is not good enough). A user could add in a part of an SQL Command and ruin the database. You should convert it to a Decimal like you already did and then use SqlParameters. SQL Server will then analyze the command with the parameter as an unknown, compile an execution plan and then use the parameter ONLY when it starts performing the plan.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the number decimal with no commas like "15000.00":

```
FormatNumber(nv, , , , 0)
```